# HTML Footer at Bottom

Tags: html

I am trying to program a website with HTML. This works very well, but I want the footer to be at the bottom of the website!

```
footer {        
    background-color: #F2F2F2;
    border: 1px solid #DEDCD9;
    border-radius: 5px;
    clear: both;
}
```

no error

Comment: If I write position: absolute;
and bottom: 0; then it's buggy

Comment: You can see my website on https://therealjan.github.io

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a **2-column layout** with the **footer always at the bottom**, also using Bootstrap 4 grid for responsiveness:

```css
#wrapper {
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div id="wrapper" class="d-flex flex-column">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-dark navbar-dark">
    <!-- Brand -->
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>

    <!-- Toggler/collapsibe Button -->
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

    <!-- Navbar links -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="container mt-3">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-lg-9">
        <p class="text-justify">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ut quas quae placeat non, eligendi odio, sit animi corporis unde fugiat ex est reprehenderit voluptas facilis quo amet nisi consequuntur perferendis.</p>
        <p class="text-justify">Eius reiciendis, modi nam magni, vel et, labore sit perspiciatis obcaecati illo aspernatur laboriosam, sed veritatis nisi deleniti quae alias nesciunt. Et possimus, reprehenderit voluptatibus officiis consequatur illo architecto magnam!</p>
        <p class="text-justify">Qui tempora deserunt, corrupti soluta obcaecati ab fugiat consectetur? Asperiores ullam aliquid recusandae doloribus voluptate ipsa. Reprehenderit aspernatur est dolore ipsum voluptatum doloribus atque suscipit. Quod voluptatum, facere temporibus
          iure.</p>
        <p class="text-justify">Ipsum quasi, iste fugit doloribus accusantium natus provident, dolorum molestiae alias. Quo earum explicabo corporis assumenda autem ratione ea corrupti tenetur, fugit esse doloremque, laborum, ab iste eum. Mollitia, consectetur!</p>
        <p class="text-justify">Eligendi dolores nisi quibusdam, officia earum neque harum iure reprehenderit voluptates, veritatis quaerat deserunt ratione porro itaque rem voluptatum minima similique temporibus unde! Quaerat laborum ullam optio sequi quae quidem!</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-3 mb-3">
        <ul class="list-group">
          <li class="list-group-item">First item</li>
          <li class="list-group-item">Second item</li>
          <li class="list-group-item">Third item</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer mt-auto text-center p-2 bg-light">
    &copy; Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope it helps.